# How does Elastic Search aggregations get updated in ecommerce sites

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

There are multiple aggregations in ecommerce site, if a user select a filter, how does other aggregations get updated? whether individual request is sent for every aggregation or single request will handle all the aggregations updation.

Example:

**Brand:**
  abc(100)
  xyz(50)

**Color:**
  red(110)
  white(40)

**size:**
  medium(60)
  small(40)
  large(50)

if a user selects 'red' and 'medium'
whether a individual requests for 'Color' aggregation and 'Size' aggregations will be sent?
Explain how does this happen in real time e-commerce sites

Comment: The doc seems quite clear https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html : you can define multiple aggregations in your query on top of whatever filter you have.

Comment: Thanks,i have gone through it, my question is how each aggregation will be updated along with search results. can you explain the execution flow what happens when a aggregation filter is selected by user in real time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say brand "brand1" and "brand2" are selected, color "color1" and "color2" are selected and size "size1" and "size2" are selected.

Results will only show products such that each product satisfies all the conditions below:

- Its brand is "brand1" or "brand2"
- Its color is either "color1" or "color2"
- Its size is either "size1" or "size2"

Aggregation results of category Brand will be filtered on all products such that each product satisfies all the conditions below:

- Its color is either "color1" or "color2"
- Its size is either "size1" or "size2"

Similar will be the case for Color and Size categories.

Taking all of this into consideration, we can create a single Elasticsearch query request to give all results as well as all aggregations (See below).

```
POST _search
{
   "filter": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "terms": {
                  "brand": [
                     "brand1",
                     "brand2"
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "terms": {
                  "color": [
                     "color1",
                     "color2"
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "terms": {
                  "size": [
                     "size1",
                     "size2"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "filtered_brand_aggs": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "terms": {
                        "color": [
                           "color1",
                           "color2"
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "terms": {
                        "size": [
                           "size1",
                           "size2"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "aggs": {
            "brand_aggs": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "brand"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "filtered_color_aggs": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "terms": {
                        "brand": [
                           "brand1",
                           "brand2"
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "terms": {
                        "size": [
                           "size1",
                           "size2"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "aggs": {
            "color_aggs": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "color"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "filtered_size_aggs": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "terms": {
                        "color": [
                           "color1",
                           "color2"
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "terms": {
                        "brand": [
                           "brand1",
                           "brand2"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "aggs": {
            "size_aggs": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "size"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is the most generalized query. Of course this query has to be modified according to the filter selections. If say no Brand filter is selected, all the `terms` filter for brand field will go away. Same goes for the other fields. When no filters are selected, you basically end up with the query below:

```
POST _search
{
   "aggs": {
      "brand_aggs": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "brand"
         }
      },
      "color_aggs": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "color"
         }
      },
      "size_aggs": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "size"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So every time a filter selection changes, a new query is fired and results and aggregations updated.

Comment: Thanks  @bittusarkar for the detailed explanation.